# When/why does split_on_silence() return an empty list

Tags: python, pydub

I'm trying to take an mp3 and simply remove silent blocks. I'm using `pydub.split_on_silence()`, but it returns an empty list. In my code below, the audio chunk seems to be silent for the first 4 seconds, has 12 seconds of audio, then is silent for the remainder.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.silence import split_on_silence

sound =  AudioSegment.from_mp3("audio_files/xxxxxx.mp3")
clip = sound[21*1000:45*1000]

#"graph" the volume in 1 second increments
for x in range(0,int(len(clip)/1000)):
    print(x,clip[x*1000:(x+1)*1000].max_dBFS)

chunks = split_on_silence(
    clip,
    min_silence_len=1000,
    silence_thresh=-16,
    keep_silence=100
)

print("number of chunks",len(chunks))
print (chunks)
```

Output :

```
0 -59.67942035834925
1 -59.67942035834925
2 -60.20599913279624
3 -59.18294868384861
4 -7.294483767470469
5 -9.54772815923718
6 -7.8863408992261785
7 -8.018780602216872
8 -8.086437972291877
9 -9.689721851628853
10 -12.146807891343315
11 -13.187719632532362
12 -14.065443216019279
13 -14.344275171835644
14 -14.668150366783275
15 -10.544064231686791
16 -59.67942035834925
17 -59.9387199016366
18 -58.94496421785445
19 -59.9387199016366
20 -59.42763781218885
21 -59.67942035834925
22 -60.20599913279624
23 -59.67942035834925
number of chunks 0
[]
```

Comment: Have you seen this: https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/issues/169 ?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @ggrelet.  I think the solution is that silence is judged by *average* dbfs (or just .dBFS) not *max* DBFS.  I changed my code accordingly (display the average dBFS, lower the threshold to -40) and got a non-null return.